# Permission Denied launching python script on Mint 17.3

Tags: javascript, python, applet, linux-mint, cinnamon

I have a cinnamon applet (javascript) running in the ~/.local/share/cinnamon/applets/applet@uuid/ folder that users download from Cinnamon Spices using the applet (window) in System Settings. In this javascript I launch a python script that creates a window for managing feeds.

Sometime after Feb I have started getting a permission denied error when the following code is executed, launching a python script on Mint 17.3:

```
GLib.spawn_async_with_pipes(null, argv, null, GLib.SpawnFlags.DO_NOT_REAP_CHILD, null);
```

This only happens on Mint 17.3, cinnamon installed on Fedora 23 works without an issue.

The error I get is:

```
GLib.SpawnError: Failed to execute child process
Failed to execute child process (Permission denied)
```

If the user changes the python script and gives it execute permissions then it works, however since this is downloaded and installed behind the scenes I don't think this is something I can automatically do?

Comment: How is it installed? If it is getting installed you can probably call chmod during installation?

Comment: Gets installed via the applets window in cinnamon.  I have not found much documentation around the install process for applets.
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Cinnamon#Applets_and_extensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

1. Invoke `["python", "myscript.py"]` instead of trying to execute the script directly.
2. Programmatically `chmod` it to add the executable flag

Comment: Number 1 doesn't work on mint, gives a slightly different message: Failed to execute child process "python". python does execute from the terminal so guessing this is still the same permission error.